# powershell get content from one file using array of regex and replace content within another file

Tags: arrays, regex, powershell, file

I know some programing basics but this project is far beyond my knowledge. Any help would be really appreciated, thank you in advance.

There are two files with text (see below) and I need to examine first file(regex) and replace text in another file using predefined array of patterns.
Here is the example of the code and text files, this way i would be easier to understand what I need.

```
 $file = "C:\powershell\changescript\Add.bat"
```

content of the file Add.bat:

```
@Echo Off
cd %systemroot%\system32
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "DesktopShortcut" /t REG_SZ /d "Yes" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "ModelName" /t REG_SZ /d "tochange" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "HostName" /t REG_SZ /d "tochange" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "IP Address" /t REG_SZ /d "tochange" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "SerialNo" /t REG_SZ /d "tochange" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "Services" /t REG_SZ /d "PclPrint eSCL LEDM" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "NetworkType" /t REG_SZ /d "Ethernet" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "MAC" /t REG_SZ /d "tochange" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "Manufacturer" /t REG_SZ /d "Hewlett-Packard" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "GUID" /t REG_SZ /d "tochange" /f
xcopy "C:\applications\TwainConfig\*" "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\" /s /i /Y
Cls
Exit

 $filemin = "C:\powershell\changescript\pc.txt"
```

content of the file pc.txt:

```
ModelName       : HP Color LaserJet Pro M478fxxx
HostName        : EPxxxxxx
IP Address      : 192.x.x.x
SerialNo        : CNBxx3P8WY
Services        : PclPrint RestScan eSCL LEDM Fax
MAC             : c4651645xxb95
GUID            : urn:uuid:8866a4ce-2da1-5b24-6af5-13e5dc7f63b5
```

This isn't working but describe what I need (at-least I think it describe..)

```
$filemin = "C:\powershell\changescript\pc.txt"
      $findThisAndReplace = @(
            $paternchange1 = '"ModelName" /t REG_SZ /d "tochange" /f"',
            $paternchange2 = '"HostName" /t REG_SZ /d "tochange" /f"',
            $paternchange3 = '"IP Address" /t REG_SZ /d "tochange" /f"',
            $paternchange4 = '"SerialNo" /t REG_SZ /d "tochange" /f"',
            $paternchange5 = '"MAC" /t REG_SZ /d "tochange" /f"',
            $paternchange6 = '"GUID" /t REG_SZ /d "tochange" /f"'
            )
            $file = "C:\powershell\changescript\AddScan.bat"
      $replaceWith = @(
            $paternget1 = '"ModelName       : *',
            $paternget2 = '"HostName        : *',
            $paternget3 = '"IP Address      : *',
            $paternget4 = '"SerialNo        : *',
            $paternget5 = '"MAC             : *',
            $paternget6 = '"GUID            : *'
            )
    function getsetcontent ($patern, $filemin, $file){
    $i=0;
    while $1 !> 7
    do
    (get-content $file) | ForEach-Object {$i++;$_ -Replace $patternchange$i, "$paternget$i"} | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 $filemin}
```

Result after merge should be :

```
@Echo Off
cd %systemroot%\system32
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "DesktopShortcut" /t REG_SZ /d "Yes" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "ModelName" /t REG_SZ /d "HP Color LaserJet Pro M478fxxx" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "HostName" /t REG_SZ /d "EPxxxxxx" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "IP Address" /t REG_SZ /d "192.x.x.x" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "SerialNo" /t REG_SZ /d "CNBxx3P8WY" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "Services" /t REG_SZ /d "PclPrint eSCL LEDM" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "NetworkType" /t REG_SZ /d "Ethernet" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "MAC" /t REG_SZ /d "c4651645xxb95" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "Manufacturer" /t REG_SZ /d "Hewlett-Packard" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "GUID" /t REG_SZ /d "urn:uuid:8866a4ce-2da1-5b24-6af5-13e5dc7f63b5" /f
xcopy "C:\applications\TwainConfig\*" "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\" /s /i /Y
Cls
Exit
```

Comment: Nice task specification. What have you tried so far? Where are you currently stuck?

Comment: Hey, i'm stuck on getting paterns from this file $filemin = "C:\powershell\changescript\pc.txt" . And placing them in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem with the following piece of code:

```
((Get-Content pc.txt) -replace '^([^:]+):', '$1=' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-StringData).GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object -Process { New-Variable -Name $_.key -Value $_.Value -Force }
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString(((Get-Content Add.bat) -replace '("([^"]+)"[^"]+)"tochange"', '$1"${$2}"' | Out-String)) | Set-Content AddNew.bat -PassThru
```

Result:

```
@Echo Off
cd %systemroot%\system32
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "DesktopShortcut" /t REG_SZ /d "Yes" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "ModelName" /t REG_SZ /d "HP Color LaserJet Pro M478fxxx" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "HostName" /t REG_SZ /d "EPxxxxxx" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "IP Address" /t REG_SZ /d "192.x.x.x" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "SerialNo" /t REG_SZ /d "CNBxx3P8WY" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "Services" /t REG_SZ /d "PclPrint RestScan eSCL LEDM Fax" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "NetworkType" /t REG_SZ /d "Ethernet" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "MAC" /t REG_SZ /d "c4651645xxb95" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "Manufacturer" /t REG_SZ /d "Hewlett-Packard" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "GUID" /t REG_SZ /d "urn:uuid:8866a4ce-2da1-5b24-6af5-13e5dc7f63b5" /f
xcopy "C:\applications\TwainConfig\*" "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\" /s /i /Y
Cls
Exit
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/avSQZo/1) for the `pc.txt` file.

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/f1ZjrL/1) for the `Add.bat` file.

Comment: Problem is that this files are generated by another script :
$comp=$args[0]
echo $comp
$logFile = "c:\temp\$comp.txt"
$open = "\\$comp\c$\temp\$comp.txt"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -ScriptBlock { 
$SID = (New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.DiskQuota).TranslateLogonNameToSID((Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $Using:comp -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).Username)
$list = Get-ItemProperty registry::HKEY_USERS\$($SID)\SOFTWARE\HP\HPtwain | Where-Object {$_ -Match "HostName"} | Out-File $Using:logFile 
}

Comment: @filbrinza, Ok, let's leave it as it was :) Check out my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you (regex rulez)

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to read the `pc.txt` with the registryvalue names and the replacement strings and convert that to an easy to use Hashtable.

Then loop over your .bat file line by line and make the changes:

```
# organize the values from 'pc.txt' into a Hashtable
# read the file as single multiline string and replace the first colon (:)
# of every line into an equals sign (=). 
# then use ConvertFrom-StringData to obtain a Hashtable
$pcHash = (Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\pc.txt' -Raw) -replace '(?m)^(.*?):','$1=' | ConvertFrom-StringData
# read the 'Add.bat' as string array
$bat = (Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\Add.bat') | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^Reg.*/v\s+"([^"]+)".*"(tochange)"') {
        if ($pcHash.ContainsKey($matches[1])) {
            # output this line updated
            $_ -replace $matches[2], $pcHash[$matches[1]]
        }
    }
    else {
        # output the line unchanged
        $_
    }
}

# output to (new) file. -PassThru will also show the result on screen
$bat | Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\New.bat' -PassThru
```

Result:

```
@Echo Off
cd %systemroot%\system32
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "DesktopShortcut" /t REG_SZ /d "Yes" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "ModelName" /t REG_SZ /d "HP Color LaserJet Pro M478fxxx" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "HostName" /t REG_SZ /d "EPxxxxxx" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "IP Address" /t REG_SZ /d "192.x.x.x" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "SerialNo" /t REG_SZ /d "CNBxx3P8WY" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "Services" /t REG_SZ /d "PclPrint eSCL LEDM" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "NetworkType" /t REG_SZ /d "Ethernet" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "MAC" /t REG_SZ /d "c4651645xxb95" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "Manufacturer" /t REG_SZ /d "Hewlett-Packard" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\HP\HPTwain" /v "GUID" /t REG_SZ /d "urn:uuid:8866a4ce-2da1-5b24-6af5-13e5dc7f63b5" /f
xcopy "C:\applications\TwainConfig\*" "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\" /s /i /Y
Cls
Exit
```

Regex details:

```
^                 Assert position at the beginning of the string
Reg               Match the characters “Reg” literally
.                 Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *              Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
/v                Match the characters “/v” literally
\s                Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   +              Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"                 Match the character “"” literally
(                 Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [^"]            Match any character that is NOT a “"”
      +           Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
) 
"                 Match the character “"” literally               
.                 Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *              Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"                 Match the character “"” literally
(                 Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   tochange       Match the characters “tochange” literally
)
"                 Match the character “"” literally
```

Comment: Your solution is perfectly working. And is very elegant. One little problem is that I get  :
PSPath          : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1414065607-2312316
                  653-3939627664-20885\SOFTWARE\HP\HPtwain
PSParentPath    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1414065607-2312316
                  653-3939627664-20885\SOFTWARE\HP
PSChildName     : HPtwain
PSProvider      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry

This lines as well in my first script and it breaks your regex. I know it is my own fault not posting it in first instance.

Comment: issue has been solved by adding "Select-Object * -exclude PSPath,PSParentPath, PSChildName, PSProvider, PSDrive" to my original script, thank you again, really appreciate it.